# clean deletes simulator in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

clean.bat file removes my simulator also, can anyone help me out in solving this error?

I tried reinstalling eclipse, but next time when I run clean.bat again this error appears.

Comment: this is pretty tangential to programming.  Try the BlackBerry forums.

Comment: @michael:Thanks for your reply, I will try in BBforums

Answer (score 0):

Clean.bat does the following:

- sets read-only file attribute to all files that are listed in "_manifest" file
- removes every file that has no read-only attrib from its directory
- unsets read-only attribute.

So, check the contents of your `_manifest` file. Everything except listed there are removed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,manifest file is also missing, all I am left with is JAVA and DEBUG folder

Comment: Do you have _manifest file BEFORE you run clean.bat? (before everything disappears) What are its contents?

Comment: I have _mainfest before clean.bat, it is also missing after I perform simulator clean. OS used is windows7

Comment: When I perform device clean in eclipse installed on WidowsXP it is not showing similar behavior, does it got to do with the OS I am running it on?

Comment: I fixed this issue Reg, actually I found an alternative way to clean my simulator instead of running clean.bat in net>comp>simul, I am selecting clean from Project>Blackberry>Clean so this action is avoiding the trouble!